# latex chapter not included in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I have created chapter by

```
\chapter{"one"}
```

I want this to be visible in my table of contents but when I do `\tableofcontents`. I cannot see them. Can anyone tell me how to include chapters in table of contents? I am using latex in ubuntu 12.04. For instance if `\chapter{"one"}` is in page 20 and is the third chapter. Then in table of contents I should see `3. One    20` Something like this.

### Edited version

Here is a small sample latex script. I have used [acm template](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/):

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtap]{acmlarge}

\acmArticle{n}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlFnt{\algofont}
\SetAlCapFnt{\algofont}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\algofont}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\IncMargin{-\parindent}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}

% Title portion
\title{Sample text}
\author{Sadiksha}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagebreak

\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\chapter{ABC}
this is a content

\end{document}
```

I can see a title page, table of contents with no `ABC` in it, just `Contents`.

The link to the template is: http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/acm-large-v1-3.zip

Comment: Tables of contents in LaTeX need several (typically 2) compilation passes to reflect changes properly. Have you made sure you ran the `latex` command at least twice? Also, could you make a small, standalone example that reproduces the problem, and include it in your question?

Comment: yes I did run it twice but with no result. Actually I am using acm template.

Comment: Please add to your question a minimal and complete document showing the relevant settings.

Comment: Your document class is unknown. Please use a standard one or provide a link to this document class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The largest sectional unit supported by the [acmlarge document class](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/) is `\section`. For some reason, `\chapter` is defined to `\relax`, so using it doesn't cause an error, but it doesn't create a chapter either.